# Why are questions randomly being closed and marked as "shopping requests" when they are not?

Tags: discussion

I would really like to understand how [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1803833/kvm-switch-vs-multiple-v-switches-plus-km-switch) questions is supposed to be a "shopping request", when there is

1. no request for specific products or manufacturers
2. I clearly am discussing a most general hardware setup question.

I hope this mod behaviour does not reflect the spirit of this community that I just recently joined.

Comment: Even if you disregard the recommendation-y stuff, it's still opinion-based.

Comment: @DanielB No, I am trying to understand if there is an underlying technical advantage to the KVM solution that I am missing. At no point was I asking for an "opinion", I precisely asked what the advantage is.

Comment: Maybe just rephrase the question a bit instead of accusing the mods of being abusive? Or maybe do both. Or neither. I don't wanna tell you how to live your life but ehm... other options are available. If you rephrase it a bit its probably easy to get it reopenend

Comment: @Gantendo I raise the accusation because it is the 2nd time this has happened today. https://superuser.com/questions/1803774/kvm-switch-to-computer-with-a-docking-station-inbetween In my first question I was asking about compatibility issues. Yes, there was a recommendation question, but it was totally optional and "on the side", which is indicated by it being the last sentence and beginning with an "Also, ...".

Comment: This site is confusing as fuck and the rules and unwritten rules will feel unfair. But if you stick with it for a bit you also notice that some people here are knowledgeable as fuck and not everyone is a dick (except me, I am)

Comment: @Gantendo I'm not new to SA, just SuperUser. SA has saved me so many times and I love the community in general, which is why I feel really bitter right now.

Comment: Asking why a question was closed is something else than stating you're subjected to abusive mod behavior.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen I may have overreacted here, true. But the repeated closing of questions  that were definitely not shopping requests let to me being upset and questioning the mod behaviour. Let's get back to why the question was closed then. What did I do wrong?

Comment: If they see phrases like `where I can buy` and `are there certain manufacturers that can be recommended` and words like `cheaper` and `amazon` the mods might get confused about your true intentions

Comment: @Gantendo Okay, I get that. But tbh, if they put that little effort in reading the question and the context, one could just as well let a bot do it.

Comment: What you can't see (and I don't blame you) is that our mods are incredibly underpaid (we call em "volunteers" but everyone knows its just an abusive relationship) and overworked. A bot would do everything correctly. Humans make mistakes, and most of our mods are human. One of our mods is literally a cute dog tho.

Comment: @Gantendo I get that too and I also find it highly problematic. But wouldnt a more relaxed question handling strategy be in ordner then? It does more harm to unnecessarily close questions than leave some open that a harder to decide. Am I wrong?

Comment: You are the worst form of wrong. Correct. But imagine you find yourself in their shoes (god forbid). And you see an endless stream of shitty ill-formatted questions that break the rules in one way or another. And you have only a small set of close reasons. People will complain no matter what you do. Will you end up relaxed or will you close everything that is imperfect? People who don't smoke weed end up a bit, you know, triggerhappy. They are idealists; if they weren't they would do something more fun. So they are dreaming of a site full of perfect questions with perfect answers.

Comment: @Gantendo Thank you for taking the time to explain to me, I learned a little bit more about the SA community in general. I still hope they reopen my question, but I do understand them to some degree now.

Comment: Honestly, I agree with you @Felix. I do think the mod jumped the gun on this one and although you may have used a bit of poor wording, the quesiton itself should be perfectly fine. Instead of hoping that its going to be reopened, I think it might be a better idea to give the question a bit more thought and then post a new one. Try to use the wording why is..., rather than I'm wondering to attract factual answers.

Comment: My mistake, I saw "where I can buy the switch" in a separate statement within parentheses while reading and mistook it for a separate recommendation. I have reopened and edited to remove all the parentheticals which honestly make it difficult to read.

Comment: @Mokubai Would you be so kind to take a look at their other question (if you haven't already)?

Comment: @Gantendo That one needs work in my opinion. "are there certain manufacturers that can be recommended"  is a bit too close to asking us to go shopping, and on top of that "Are there commonly connection or compatibility issues?" is too broad, and vague. I'm fine reopening the one I closed at is was a mistake in reading, but that other one *is* off topic to me.

Comment: @Mokubai That's fair. When Felix returns they can use your feedback to improve it a bit.

Comment: @Mokubai Thank you for reopening the 2nd question. I will try to write more clearly with less parentheses and split my text into shorter sentences in the future to avoid confusion. If I still need my first question answered, I will edit it as you are suggesting. I am glad we have come to an understanding, thank you all for the constructive dialogue.

Comment: Something I find helpful is to remember that my own question  is only just one question, one little error where some small misuse of language caused it to attract down or close votes, but that those doing the down- and close-voting are not just looking at my question, but dozens and more of bigger and smaller errors than mine, and my errors are "just another problem" to them, rather than a personal effort that went a little awry. Being aware of this allows me to focus on fixing the errors I've made.

Comment: Laser-focus in the question, re-reading it before posting to make sure I'm focused only on the problem at hand. Clearly stating my intent at the beginning and then restating it at the end when appropriate. Reading it again to make sure each line is information useful to those who might know the solution. Making sure I "showed my homework", demonstrating the research I've done and what I've tried and the outcomes and how those failed to meet my needs. All these are things I try to keep in my personal checklist when asking here. I AM coming with hat in hand, as it were, and showing that helps.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My mistake, I saw "where I can buy the switch" in a separate statement within parentheses while reading and mistook it for a separate recommendation.

I have reopened and edited to remove all the parentheticals which honestly make it difficult to read.