# What do you use to quickly post boilerplate responses?

Tags: discussion, user-interface

What do you use to quickly post boilerplate responses? I am using a simple Tampermonkey script but I, as a Bear of Very Little Brain, am open to suggestions.

I'm not just looking for improvements/alternatives to the script but also improvements to the boilerplate messages.

(yes I am so old I used tables for layout)

https://pastebin.com/QCTerxx2

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm using https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments

> This script adds a little 'auto' link next to all comments boxes. When you click the link, you see a popup with customizable auto-comments (canned responses), which you can easily click to insert.

Here are my custom comments (feel free to import these):

```
###[Q] Off topic
You are asking an off-topic question. Please read [help/on-topic], [ask] and [help/dont-ask].

###[A] Thanks
Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](https://$SITEURL$/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the $SITENAME$ way of saying thank you.

###[A] Link
Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

### Edit
Rather than adding details in comments, please [edit] your question to add requested information. You can then comment saying that you have done so. Comments here may get hidden by "show more comments" or could be deleted without notice. Editing updates into your question ensures that they don't get lost and that everybody who wants to answer the question sees them.

###[A] Not an answer
This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://$SITEURL$/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://$SITEURL$/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174).

###[Q] Software shopping
You are asking an off-topic question. Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [on-topic](https://$SITEURL$/help/on-topic). Try [softwarerecs.se],  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

###[Q] Hardware shopping
You are asking an off-topic question (hardware shopping). Please read [on-topic](https://$SITEURL$/help/on-topic) , [ask] and [help/dont-ask]. Try [hardwarerecs.se],  but please first read [What is required for a question to be 'high quality'?"](http://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-be-high-quality).

###[Q] Script
Please note that https://$SITEURL$ is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

###[Q] Research
Questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

###[Q] Corporate
Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

###[Q] Programming
Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [on-topic](https://$SITEURL$/help/on-topic) . Try [SO] but please first read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 

###[Q] Blocked
You are question blocked on [so]. That doesn't mean you can ask your off-topic programming questions on [su]. See [on-topic](https://$SITEURL$/help/on-topic). Please also read [ask] and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://$SITEURL$/help/dont-ask)

###[Q] Diagram/Image
Some diagrams or screen shots of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you. 

###[Q] Code Images
Sorry, we can't accept images of code or errors. Post those as text, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

###[Q] Crosspost
Please do **not** crosspost. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/267099 

###[A] Recommend
Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

###[A] OP answer
Please use the **Post Your Answer** button only for actual answers. You should edit your original post to add additional information.

###[A] New question as answer
This is **not** an answer to the original question. If you have a new question please [ask your own question](https://$SITEURL$/questions/ask) (referencing this one for context if it helps).

###[A] Me too
Please don't leave answers stating that you have the same problem as the one described in the question. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](https://$SITEURL$/privileges/vote-up) the question. You can also "save" it or "follow" it (which will notify you of any new answers).

###[Q] No answer
Please read [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://$SITEURL$/help/no-one-answers)

###[A] Explain
While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.

###[A] Code only
Could you please [edit] your answer to give an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution.

###[Q] Answer in question
Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. Please read [Can I answer my own question?](https://$SITEURL$/help/self-answer)

###[A] Please read again
Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

###[A] Duplicate answer
This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.

###[A] Reference
Please read [How to reference material written by others](https://$SITEURL$/help/referencing). You must block quote text that has been written by some else. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help). I've fixed it for you this time, but please pay attention to this in future.

###[A] Duplicate multiple answers
Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://$SITEURL$/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://$SITEURL$/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

###[Q] Tags
Please read the tags **before** posting your question. You are asking an off-topic question. See [help/on-topic].

###[Q] Legal or Licensing Question
I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because licensing advice is off-topic on $SITENAME$. You may be able to get help on https://opensource.stackexchange.com/, but read their faq carefully before proceeding.

###[Q] We are not Customer Support
I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

###[A] Promotion
Please note if you want to promote or recommend your own product/blog, there are some [guidelines in place](https://$SITEURL$/help/promotion) for doing so. Following them will help you avoid giving the impression that you're spamming. Could you please [edit] to explicitly state your affiliation? Thanks. (If you're not actually affiliated, it may be worth mentioning that as well.)

### English only
[su] is an English-only site, and all the questions and answers must be in English.

### Vandalism
Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)).  By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

### Duplicate Account
It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://$SITEURL$//help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

###[Q] Research
Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Please [edit] your question and tell us what you have tried.This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!
```

Comment: I think this has been the 'standard' for this from when I was a newish user for good reason. It works pretty well ;)

Comment: Thank you both that looks pretty awesome!

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Mentioned you over at [this thread](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/15070/why-are-questions-randomly-being-closed-and-marked-as-shopping-requests-when-t) btw hope thats OK

Comment: Woof? More seriously, that fuzzball's gotten me a lot of goodwill over the years :D